# How to construct a numpy array with its each element be the minimum value of all possible values?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to construct a 1d numpy array `a`, and I know each `a[i]` has several possible values. Of course, the numbers of the possible values of any two elements of `a` can be different. For each `a[i]`, I want to set it be the minimum value of all the possible values.

For example, I have two array:

```
idx = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3])
val = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3])
```

The array I want to construct is following:

```
a = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1])
```

So does there exist any function in numpy can finish this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def groupby_minimum(idx, val):
    sidx = idx.argsort()
    sorted_idx = idx[sidx]
    cut_idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(sorted_idx[1:] != sorted_idx[:-1])+1]
    return np.minimum.reduceat(val[sidx], cut_idx)
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: idx = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3])
    ...: val = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3])
    ...: 

In [37]: groupby_minimum(idx, val)
Out[37]: array([ 0.1,  0.5,  0.6,  0.1])
```

---

Here's another using `pandas` -

```
import pandas as pd

def pandas_groupby_minimum(idx, val):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : idx, 'val' : val})
    return df.groupby('ID')['val'].min().values
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: pandas_groupby_minimum(idx, val)
Out[66]: array([ 0.1,  0.5,  0.6,  0.1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `binned_statistic`:

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

idx_list=np.append(np.unique(idx),np.max(idx)+1)
stats=binned_statistic(idx,val,statistic='min', bins=idx_list)
a=stats.statistic
```

I think, in older scipy versions, `statistic='min'` was not implemented, but you can use `statistic=np.min` instead. Intervals are half open in `binned_statistic`, so this implementation is safe.